# How to sort a Future<List> data type on DataTable widget in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart, flutter-http

I have a problem for sorting a list from Future data type in DataTable widget

```
class User {
  final String idUser,
  name,
  phone;

  User(
    {this.idUser,
    this.name,
    this.phone});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
    idUser: json['_id'],
    name: json['name'],
    phone: json['phone']);
  }
}

List<User> userFromJson(jsonData) {
  List<User> result =
    List<User>.from(jsonData.map((item) => User.fromJson(item)));

  return result;
}

// index
Future<List<User>> fetchUser() async {
  String route = AppConfig.API_ENDPOINT + "userdata";
  final response = await http.get(route);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResp = json.decode(response.body);

    return userFromJson(jsonResp);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed load $route, status : ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

I wan't to call it on DataTable widget inside a FutureBuilder widget

```
int sortColumnIndex=0;
bool isAscending = true;
bool sort=false;
Future<List<User>> user;
User = fetchUser();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return FutureBuilder(
        future: user,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
              children: <Widget>[
                // Table
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: dataBody(snapshot.data)
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),                  
              ],
            );
          }
          return Center();            
        },
      );
    }
```

The dataBody function is:

```
SingleChildScrollView dataBody(List<User> listUser) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: DataTable(
      sortAscending: isAscending,
      sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
      showCheckboxColumn: false,
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Name"),
          numeric: false,
          tooltip: "Name",
          onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) { 
            setState(() {sort = !sort;
            });
            onSortColumn(columnIndex, ascending);
          }),
        DataColumn(
            label: Text("Phone"),
            numeric: false,
            tooltip: "Phone"
        ),       
    ],
    
    rows: listUser
      .map(
        (user) => DataRow(
        onSelectChanged: (b) {
          print(user.name);
        },
        cells: [
          DataCell(
              Text(user.name)
          ),
          DataCell(
              Text(user.phone)
          ),
        ]),
      ).toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

while the onSortColumn function is like this:

```
onSortColumn(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
  if (columnIndex == 0) {
    if (ascending) {
      user.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    } else {
      user.sort((a, b) => b.name.compareTo(a.name));
    }
  }
}
```

it just like the word "sort" in "onSortColumn" turn out underlined red and give a message like this:

> The method 'sort' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'sort'.

if there are another ways to sorting, please let me know, thank you very much

Comment: you have to access the ```listUser``` not the ```user```. ```user``` is ```Future``` that should be dealt with by ```FutureBuilder``` and the actual data from the complete```Future``` is ```snapshot.data``` which was given to the parameter of the fuction ```dataBody``` as ```listUser``` so you refer to a wrong variable here.

Comment: wait, i'm not clearly understand, so according to it, what variable needs to be replaced, and what variable must replace it?

Comment: oh I understand now, thank you very much, also please answer it on answer section to ease the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sortColumnIndex=0;
bool isAscending = true;
bool sort=false;
Future<List<User>> userList;
List<User> users;
User = fetchUser();

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder(
     future: userList,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if(!snapshot.hasData) {
         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
       }

       if(snapshot.hasData) {
          users = snapshot.data;
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
            children: <Widget>[
            // Table
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: dataBody(users)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),                  
          ],
        );
      }
      return Center();            
    },
  );
}
```

Then for sorting function

```
onSortColumn(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
  if (columnIndex == 0) {
    if (ascending) {
      users.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    } else {
      users.sort((a, b) => b.name.compareTo(a.name));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but I get more effective ways using directly dataBody(snapshot.data)